# ArgumentError: Invalid option: harmony when deploying Rails 5 app to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a newbie to Heroku and am having trouble deploying an updated version of my Rails 5 app due to an Uglifier-related error.

I have a version of my app currently deployed on Heroku, but none of my JS files are loading there. They load and function fine on localhost:3000.

I figured it was an issue related to Uglifier. After reading another person's similar issue on SO, I tried his solution of downgrading the Uglifier gem; my Gemfile previously specified '>= 1.3.0', so Heroku had automatically installed 4.1.20. I therefore changed my Gemfile to: gem 'uglifier', '~> 3.0.4').

When I push to Heroku now, though, I get this error message:

```
...
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.4
remote:        Bundle complete! 24 Gemfile dependencies, 77 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (3.33s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Removing uglifier (4.1.20)
remote:        The latest bundler is 2.0.1, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
remote:        To update, run `gem install bundler`
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.14.1-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ArgumentError: Invalid option: harmony
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:129:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:128:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-3.0.4/lib/uglifier.rb:128:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/config/environments/production.rb:26:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/config/environments/production.rb:26:in `block in <main>
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `instance_eval'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:216:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:602:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:601:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_5ce011f911fe1c351bbce1885a611ecb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Line 26 of my production.rb file is this:
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Is harmony not compatible with this version of Uglifier?

Comment: So since posting this, I changed back my Gemfile so that Heroku would use version 4.1.20 of Uglifier. I also ran rake assets:clobber to clear out my public/assets folder and then precompiled again. Pushed it to Heroku and it deployed fine...but the JS files still aren't loading. Any tips? I feel like I've tried nearly all the suggestions related to this problem on SO, but none have worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working! I had to go into my application.js file and remove '/=require jquery-ujs'. The file already included '/=require rails-ujs', so jquery-ujs is unnecessary (and in my case, was completely preventing my app from working properly!).

My application.js file:

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require rails-ujs
    //= require activestorage
    //= require_tree .
```

To be honest, I was getting a warning in my console about not needing to require both of these. However, since I didn't encounter any JS/jQuery-related issues locally, I ignored the warning. Lo and behold, it was the culprit behind preventing my JS files from loading properly on Heroku. Moral of the story: Don't ignore those warnings.